# Trigger Mysql time

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de construir un trigger lo cual no tengo nada de experiencia pero logre encontrar algo parecido a lo que busco. mi objetivo es básicamente ejecutar una acción en una tabla cada 1 minuto, esta acción debería eliminar ese registro en caso que la variable tipo Time "hora_actual" sea mayor que la variable tipo Time "respawn_min"

Lo que tengo construido es esto (no logro identificar por que no funciona)

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT e_mvp
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 MINUTE
    COMMENT 'Eliminarr Registros de MVP'
    DO
      BEGIN
         SELECT TIME(TIMESTAMP(ADDTIME(`mvp_tomb`.`mvp_dead_time`,SEC_TO_TIME(`mvp_alarm`.`mvp_respawn_start`*60)))) AS respawn_min, DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ), "%H:%i:%S" ) AS hora_actual             FROM `mvp_tomb` 
         LEFT JOIN `mvp_alarm` ON `mvp_alarm`.`mvp_location` = `mvp_tomb`.`mvp_location`;
        DELETE FROM `mvp_tomb` WHERE hora_actual > respawn_min;
      END |

delimiter ;
```

la consulta select lo que me trae son las dos fechas que debería comparar una vez teniendo esas dos variables ejecutar el DELETE cuando se cupla la condición del WHERE

Ejemplo

```
respawn_min: "20:00:00" || hora_actual: "20:02:00" || TRIGGER ELIMINAR
respawn_min: "20:00:00" || hora_actual: "19:58:00" || TRIGGER NINGUNA ACCION
respawn_min: "23:59:00" || hora_actual: "00:02:00" || TRIGGER ELIMINAR
```

Mis tablas

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mvp_alarm`(
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `mvp_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `mvp_location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `mvp_respawn_start` int,
    `mvp_respawn_end` int,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mvp_tomb`(
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `mvp_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `mvp_location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `mvp_dead_time` time NOT NULL,
    `player_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: ¿Puede agregar las estructuras de las tablas `mvp_tomb` y `mvp_alarm` para una mejor comprensión?

Comment: Listo, ya están agregadas mi tablas

Comment: Entiendo que la sentencia `DELETE FROM \`mvp_tomb\` WHERE hora_actual > respawn_min;` intenta eliminar los registros que cumplan con la condición, pero la condición en el `WHERE` no incluye ninguna columna de la tabla `mvp_tomb`, es decir, `hora_actual > respawn_min` será `TRUE` o `FALSE` y aplicará a todos los registros de la tabla. Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c51639c6206cb936a7ac565094990a4f).

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en el SELEC antes del DELETE traigo datos de dos tablas diferentes las lo cual me da como resultado "hora_actual" y "respawn_min" entonces esas dos son las que quiero usar para el TRIGGER. La "hora_actual" es simplemente la hora actual y "respawn_min" es la suma de `mvp_tomb`.`mvp_dead_time` mas `mvp_alarm`.`mvp_respawn_start` ( "20:00:00" + 300 min). El resultado me lo entrega en tipo TIME

Comment: Realmente está usando un evento (`EVENT`) que es distinto a un disparador (`TRIGGER`). Entiendo que de la sentencia `SELECT` anterior a la sentencia `DELETE` intenta obtener `hora_actual` y `respawn_min`, pero no las está almacenando en variables y una restricción de `EVENT` es que no pueden contener una sentencia `SELECT` a menos que las almacene en variables.

Comment: Aquí una opción que le puede ser útil [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=20a3abdb12f910cd52e9253e2a8f913b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
DELETE FROM `mvp_tomb`
  WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT mvp_tomb.id,TIME(TIMESTAMP(ADDTIME(
            `mvp_tomb`.`mvp_dead_time`,
            SEC_TO_TIME(`mvp_alarm`.`mvp_respawn_start`*60)
          ))) AS respawn_min, 
          DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ), "%H:%i:%S" ) AS hora_actual 
          FROM `mvp_tomb` LEFT JOIN `mvp_alarm` 
          ON `mvp_alarm`.`mvp_location` = `mvp_tomb`.`mvp_location`
    ) c1 WHERE hora_actual > respawn_min  
  );
```

La he hecho de cabeza, pruébala antes sustituyendo `DELETE` por un `SELECT *` y, si borra lo que tiene que borrar, la metes directamente en el `EVENT` sustituyendo al `SELECT` y `DELETE` que ya tienes.

Ya me cuentas

Comment: Entiendo la consulta pero me devuelve todos los valores es como si la parte de c1 WHERE hora_actual > respawn_min no se estuviera ejecutando, probé dejando datos de distintas horas en mi base de datos

Comment: ¿Será que todos cumplen la condición? Aporta algún dato de ejemplo y lo comprobamos

Comment: Algo asi podria ser https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=38054a10b9514f0a1009ae31d086fd13

Comment: Arreglado, ya he modificado la respuesta y el fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=47c4bec32b6c12f1c623a8e155fc122f Es lo que tiene hacerlo de cabeza...

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue de mucha utilidad!